# Python - recursive directory hit with os.walk()

Tags: python

I'm writing a program that renames files and directories by taking out a certain pattern.
My renaming function works well for files since os.walk() targets all files, but no so much with directories

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):               # Listing the files
        for i, foldername in enumerate(dirs):
            output = foldername.replace(pattern, "")  # Taking out pattern
            if output != foldername:
                os.rename(                            # Renaming
                    os.path.join(path, foldername),
                    os.path.join(path, output))
            else:
                pass
```

Could someone suggest a solution to target ALL directories and not only first level ones?

Comment: set `topdown=False` to visit top level directories last.

Comment: Also the correct path should use `root`: `os.path.join(root, foldername)`

Comment: Way! Both comments are right on the spot. Make it an answer so I can tick it!

Comment: you could test the code and [post you own answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)

Comment: Heh, tried but I don't have enough reputation yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting `topdown=False` in os.walk does the trick

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path, topdown=False):  # Listing the files
    for i, name in enumerate(dirs):
        output = name.replace(pattern, "")              # Taking out pattern
        if output != name:
            os.rename(                                  # Renaming
                os.path.join(root, name),
                os.path.join(root, output))
        else:
            pass
```

Thanks to [J.F Sebastian](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4279/j-f-sebastian)!

Answer (score 0):

This will do the trick ([pymillsutils.getFiles()](http://pypi.pytho.org/pypi/pymills)):

```
def getFiles(root, pattern=".*", tests=[isfile], **kwargs):
    """getFiles(root, pattern=".*", tests=[isfile], **kwargs) -> list of files

    Return a list of files in the specified path (root)
    applying the predicates listed in tests returning
    only the files that match the pattern. Some optional
    kwargs can be specified:

    * full=True        (Return full paths)
    * recursive=True   (Recursive mode)
    """

    def test(file, tests):
        for test in tests:
            if not test(file):
                return False
        return True

    full = kwargs.get("full", False)
    recursive = kwargs.get("recursive", False)

    files = []

    for file in os.listdir(root):
        path = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, file))
        if os.path.isdir(path):
            if recursive:
                files.extend(getFiles(path, pattern, **kwargs))
        elif test(path, tests) and re.match(pattern, path):
            if full:
                files.append(path)
            else:
                files.append(file)

    return files
```

**Usage:**

```
getFiles("*.txt", recursive=True)
```

To list just directories:

```
from os.path import isdir

getFiles("*.*", tests=[isdir], recursive=True)
```

There is also a nice OOP-style library for path manipulation and traversal called [py](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/py/1.4.18) which has really nice API(s) that I quite like and use in all my projects.

Comment: Hmmm, not so sure... I'm trying to target directories, not files. os.walk() works just fine for files, that's not my problem.

Comment: The function supports traversal and listing of directories and files.